# Text Box Rotation Issue

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a macro to insert a custom watermark in my Word document.

The code works perfectly for the first two pages of the document but thereafter the the Textbox does not rotate to -45 as mentioned in the code

What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub CustomWatermark()

    Dim activeDoc As Document
    Dim rngDoc As Range
    Dim shpTextBox As Shape
    Dim lngPages As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strWatermark As String
    
    
    Set activeDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    lngPages = activeDoc.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
    
    strWatermark = InputBox("Enter Watermark")
    
    With activeDoc
    
        For i = 1 To lngPages

            Set rngDoc = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
            rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        
            Set shpTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                                            Left:=InchesToPoints(1), _
                                            Top:=InchesToPoints(4), _
                                            Width:=InchesToPoints(6), _
                                            Height:=InchesToPoints(2), _
                                            Anchor:=rngDoc)
            With shpTextBox
                .Line.Visible = msoFalse
                .Rotation = -45
                .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
                .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
                .TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
                                                
                With .TextFrame.TextRange
                    .Font.AllCaps = True
                    .Font.Size = "60"
                    .Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
                    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                    .Text = strWatermark
                    
                End With
            End With
        Next
    End With
    

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you do it by hand? Is it not more sensical to set the watermark in the footer?

Comment: If you make all the pages visible then you see that the currently-visible pages get the rotated watermark: off-screen pages get the non-rotated version.  No idea what the fix is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that, selecting all their range and doing rotation at once, works...

```
Sub CustomWatermarkBis()
    Dim activeDoc As Document, rngDoc As Range, shpTextBox As Shape
    Dim lngPages As Long, i As Long, strWatermark As String, shR As ShapeRange
    Dim arrRot As Variant, k As Long
    
    Set activeDoc = ActiveDocument
    lngPages = activeDoc.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
    ReDim arrRot(0 To lngPages - 1)
    
    strWatermark = InputBox("Enter Watermark Text")
    With activeDoc
        For i = 1 To lngPages
            Set rngDoc = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Name:=i)
            rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        
            Set shpTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                                            Left:=InchesToPoints(1), _
                                            Top:=InchesToPoints(4), _
                                            Width:=InchesToPoints(6), _
                                            Height:=InchesToPoints(2), _
                                            Anchor:=rngDoc)
            With shpTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange
                .Font.AllCaps = True
                .Font.Size = "60"
                .Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                .Text = strWatermark
            End With
            shpTextBox.Name = "T" & i
            arrRot(k) = shpTextBox.Name: k = k + 1
        Next
        Set shR = .Shapes.Range(arrRot)
    End With
    
    With shR
        .Select
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Rotation = -45
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
        .TextFrame.HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
        .TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    End With
    Selection.Collapse
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-ordering your code to add the text before changing the rotation should solve the issue. It certainly does for me in Word 365.

EDIT: That approach worked for me exactly twice and now I can't repeat it. Adding the text box to the header does work reliably though, and results in a much tidier document.

```
Sub CustomWatermarkInHeader()
  Dim activeDoc As Document
  Dim rngDoc As Range
  Dim strWatermark As String
  Dim docSection As Section
  Dim shpTextBox As Shape
    
  Set activeDoc = ActiveDocument
    
  strWatermark = InputBox("Enter Watermark")
    
  With activeDoc
    For Each docSection In .Sections
      Set rngDoc = docSection.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
      rngDoc.Collapse wdCollapseStart
      Set shpTextBox = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=InchesToPoints(1), _
        Top:=InchesToPoints(4), _
        Width:=InchesToPoints(6), _
        Height:=InchesToPoints(2), _
        Anchor:=rngDoc)
      With shpTextBox
        With .TextFrame
          .HorizontalAnchor = msoAnchorCenter
          .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
          With .TextRange
            .Font.AllCaps = True
            .Font.Size = "60"
            .Font.ColorIndex = wdGray25
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .Text = strWatermark
          End With
        End With
        .Line.Visible = msoFalse
        .Rotation = -45
        .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
      End With
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

However, you may want to consider:

1. adding the text box to the header instead of cluttering your document with a text box on every page. You will achieve the same result with fewer text boxes.
2. Using the built-in functionality to add a custom watermark. You can find this on the Design tab of the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
.Rotation = -45
```

Try:

```
.ThreeD.IncrementRotationZ -45
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.threedformat